# How do I properly set headers for GET/POST fetch to avoid CORS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cors, fetch, graphql

My goal is to POST mutation to graphQL API within React-app. While doing so I had a bug: **POST http://urlhere/graphiql 405 (Method Not Allowed)**
My function to send data:

```js
getRating = (e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let value = 2;
            const uri = '//hereIputAddress/graphiql';
    
            const query = `
            mutation{
                rating(group_id: 3, product_id: $product_id, value: $value, name: $name, phone: $phone, email: $email, content:$content) {
                product_id,
                value,
                }
            }
            `;

            const variables = {
                product_id: id,
                value: value,
                name: "wq",
                phone: "601654654",
                email: "goto@gmail.com",
                content: "some content"
            };

            const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch({ uri });
            
            apolloFetch.use(({ request, options }, next) => {
                if (!options.headers) {
                options.headers = {};
                console.log(options.headers);
                }
            
                next();
            });
            
            apolloFetch({ query, variables }).then(res =>{

            });
        }
    }
```

After some searching I realized it may be caused be lack of headers, so i changed the code to:

```js
getRating = (e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let value = 2;
            const uri = '//hereIputAddress/graphiql';
    
            const query = `
            mutation{
                rating(group_id: 3, product_id: $product_id, value: $value, name: $name, phone: $phone, email: $email, content:$content) {
                product_id,
                value,
                }
            }
            `;

            const variables = {
                product_id: id,
                value: value,
                name: "wq",
                phone: "601654654",
                email: "goto@gmail.com",
                content: "some content"
            };

            const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch({ uri });
            
            apolloFetch.use(({ request, options }, next) => {
                if (!options.headers) {
                options.headers = {};
                console.log(options.headers);
                }

                options.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true';
                options.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000';
                options.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000`'] = '1728000'; 
                options.headers['authorization'] = 'created token';
            
                next();
            });
            
            apolloFetch({ query, variables }).then(res =>{

            });
        }
    }
```

Now I have the error: `Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name`

I'm totally new to fetching data so I have completely no idea what is going on. It may be worth noting, that when I tried fetching data with GET from that server I had response: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. I 'fixed' that with downloading Allow-Cors-Allow-Origin plugin to chrome, however it doesn't seem like the best solution. My function was:

```js
const url = 'http://188.116.11.87/graphql?query=%23%20Welcome%20to%20GraphiQL%0A%23%0A%23%20GraphiQL%20is%20an%20in-browser%20IDE%20for%20writing%2C%20validating%2C%20and%0A%23%20testing%20GraphQL%20queries.%0A%23%0A%23%20Type%20queries%20into%20this%20side%20of%20the%20screen%2C%20and%20you%20will%0A%23%20see%20intelligent%20typeaheads%20aware%20of%20the%20current%20GraphQL%20type%20schema%20and%0A%23%20live%20syntax%20and%20validation%20errors%20highlighted%20within%20the%20text.%0A%23%0A%23%20To%20bring%20up%20the%20auto-complete%20at%20any%20point%2C%20just%20press%20Ctrl-Space.%0A%23%0A%23%20Press%20the%20run%20button%20above%2C%20or%20Cmd-Enter%20to%20execute%20the%20query%2C%20and%20the%20result%0A%23%20will%20appear%20in%20the%20pane%20to%20the%20right.%0A%0A%0Aquery%7B%0A%20%20product%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20description%0A%20%20%20%20keywords%0A%20%20%20%20is_published%0A%20%20%20%20author%0A%20%20%20%20attributes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20basket%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20post%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20publication_date%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%23%20last_comments(data%3A%226%22)%0A%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A'
    return fetch(url).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    }).then((data) =>{//doing stuff with data here
}
```

Here is what I found in console:
https://s1.postimg.org/2e35egfbbj/Zrzut_ekranu_2017-10-18_o_21.12.33.png

**---EDIT---** 
I tried adding headers this way:

```js
const headers = new Headers()
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    //headers.append('Content-Type','text/plain;charset=UTF-8');

    const url = 'http://myurl/graphql?
    const fetchInit = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: headers,
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'default'
    }


    return fetch(url, fetchInit)
    .then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then((data) => {...stuff here}
```

However I have bug: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

However, if I add `no-cors` mode to `fetchInit`, I get bug `Unexpected end of input` at line containing: `return response.json();`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting cors options and Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers in server side.

```js
const graphQLServer = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin(origin, callback) {
    callback(null, true);
  },
  credentials: true
};
graphQLServer.use(cors(corsOptions));
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
}
graphQLServer.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

This may help you

Answer (score 0):

You are setting headers in the request, when you should be doing so on server. Use the cors package from npm to set the cors response options.